# Making a custom previewer for store

Tags: css, image, html

I'm trying to find a way to simulate the `image-mask` property in CSS; currently it isn't available in most browsers. Is there a JavaScript library that could work?

I figured out how to do the buckles by creating a white image with a transparent space in the shape of a buckle, and then set a background color, so the background color only shows through where the image is transparent. The problem is, I can't do that for each part, because the white edges that you aren't supposed to see would be visible against the color of the part behind it (Like if you had a black square, and then you used that technique to get a red circle on it, you would end up with a red circle on a white square on a black square.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using indexed transparency - you'll want to use PNG images with 8-bit alpha channels instead. Then have an <img /\7gt; for each "component" of your item (i.e. one for the belt, one for the buckle, etc) then use absolute positioning to put each one directly on top of the other. The 8-bit transparency will ensure they all look right.

```
<div id="previewArea">
    <img class="layer2" src="buckle{color}.png" />
    <img class="layer1" src="belt{color}.png" />
    <img class="layer0" src="pants{color}.png" />
</div>
```

Of course you'd need some client scripting to swap out each image for the selected color/design.

An alternative option is to have a server-side process dynamically generate images based on given parameters, it results in simpler HTML but would be slower for your visitors - it might work as a fallback for clients that don't support scripting.

Comment: Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q77WL/ Notice the white space in between the red. I doubt that will fix it. I need to be able to change the colors of the parts with css. (wont be inline in the end) Also, it will have more layers on top of these that will partly cover the red. (I'm trying to sell custom bracelets.)


Thanks, Ian

Comment: **Edit: let me rephrase myself; I need a way to contain the background color, while having the current white places transparent. I think that explains it a little better.**